# I created a bottom navigation bar in android studio but it is not showing properly in the activity bar

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

[XML File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKIbU.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[Main Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPOVk.png)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final int main=0x7f030004;
    ActivityMainBinding activityMainBinding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        activityMainBinding=ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(activityMainBinding.getRoot());
        replaceFragment(new homeFragment());
        activityMainBinding.bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(item -> {
            if(item.getItemId()==R.id.home){
                replaceFragment(new homeFragment());
            }
            else if(item.getItemId()==R.id.history){
                replaceFragment(new historyFragment());
            }
            return true;
        });
    }
    private void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.history, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

the issue is that the homefragment is been shown on the home image rather than the activity bar. I have searched for all issue but couldn't find one for this and don't know what to do. Please help me with this issue

Comment: Not showing properly or completely not showing to the App?

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding of your question the fragment when replaced shows up in the bottom nav icon.
I guess you are loading the fragment into a wrong location ( mapping the `fragmentTransaction.replace` to the wrong element id ).
You should replace the fragment in the frame layout instead of the history button(which I guess is a menu item in the bottom navigation bar).
Code to be updated:

```
private void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.flFragment, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Hope this answer solves your issue.
Here's the documentation for the .replace function of fragment transaction : https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/transactions#java